# Pytest ignores pytest.ini file

Tags: pytest

I have pytest-django == 2.9.1 installed
I started setting up a test environment according to the instructions.
https://pytest-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html#step-2-point-pytest-to-your-django-settings

In the second step, in the root of the project, I created a pytest.ini file and added DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE there (all according to the instructions)
But when you start the test, an error appears

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting CACHES, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

But DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE is defined in the pytest.ini!
I tried putting pytest.ini in different directories, but the result is always the same.
I tried running with a parameter --ds, but the result is still the same.
Can you tell me why this happens?

**UPD**

Hmm... I remove [pytest] from the file header and got an error "no section header defined" The file does not seem to be ignored, but DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE is still not exported.

I tried adding it to the environment variables separately and received an error on startup

> export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=project.settings.test_settings
>
> pytest
>
> ImportError: Could not import settings 'project.settings.test_settings' (Is it on sys.path? Is there an import error in the settings file?): No module named project.settings.test_settings

But at startup python manage.py runserver --settings=project.settings.test_settings everything is working fine

Comment: Show your directory tree. Also, are you able to import the module? Run `python -c "import project.settings.test_settings"`, does it work?

Comment: I'm in the exact same situation. The import works for me but pytest ignores the django settings defined in the pytest.ini file. It also ignores the "TEST' key defined under "DATABASES" and uses the default anyway.

Answer (score 8):

had the same issue, there were 2 problems:

1. settings.py had a bug.
2. pytest-django was installed in a different environment.

So ensure you can import settings.py as hoefling recommended, and ensure pytest-django is actually installed in your environment

Answer (score 4):

So the [docs](https://pytest-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuring_django.html#order-of-choosing-settings) say that the order of precedence when choosing setting is

command line
environment variable
pytest.ini file.

Then it goes further to say you can override this precedence using `addopts`.
In my case, I specified my settings like below

```
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=bm.settings.ttest
addopts = --ds=bm.settings.ttest
```

And it works.